# Ruby on Rails: undefined method `min' for {......}:String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, hash

Im having troubles using the helper time_select in my RoR app.

For example, I have a form in the app to submit recipes, in the _form.html.erb I have the following field for the time

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :tiempo, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.time_select  :tiempo, :required => true,:class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%=f.error_span(:tiempo) %>
  </div>
```

and it works, but the problem is when I try to edit the recipe, im getting the following error, for example

```
undefined method `min' for "{1=>2016, 2=>1, 3=>19, 4=>19, 5=>28}":String
```

I know that is because I'm saving a Hash as a String in my database, and when I try to edit the value, time_select is looking for a hash but not a string, the problem is Im not sure how to fix it

**EDIT:**

In the end, the problem was fixed chaging the "tiempo" type from string to time

Comment: What is the type of the `tiempo` column in the database?

Comment: is a String, should I change it to date?

Comment: thanks @spickermann, I change "tiempo" type from string to time and it worked

Answer (score 2):

To store a date with a time, change the type of the database column to `datetime`.

Comment: exactly this answer. i wanted to write it and get all the reputation but you my friend had already written it.